# How to do this filter in logstash

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, filter, logstash

I have a lof file like below

xxx yyy , abc
 the count is: 100
 xxx yyy , abc

So how can I get the logstash do to pick and display like "count = 100"

I couldn't figure it out using the logstash documentation.
EDIT: For simplification, I just reduced the scope of the above problem.

Comment: If that's one "event", then you need to combine the lines using the multiline filter or codec before processing.

Comment: @AlainCollins I just modified the question, to read single line and collect data. please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore lines that you don't want, use conditionals and drop{}:

```
if [message] !~ /count/ {
    drop{}
}
```

To pull the number out of the lines that remain, use grok{}:

```
else {
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "the count is %{NUMBER:myField:int}" ]
    }
}
```

Note: written from memory; syntax may not be 100%.

Comment: Thanks much. could you explain on the drop part of the solution. like if we have many attributes like 'count' to consider, then how can we drop them. Is that a regular expression?

Comment: drop{} is a filter used to immediately stop the processing of an event in logstash.  Since your request was only to handle the "count" lines, drop{} would keep the other (unprocessed) lines from making it to elasticsearch.

Comment: ok. Lets say if I have to handle "count" line as well as "someother" lines, then can I give both of them in same if condition, if so, then how?

Comment: Your grok{} filter can have multiple patterns; by default it will use the first one that matches.